# scriptedSandbox64 fail fast exception when start asp.net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, operating-system

Good morning ,I have Asp.net Web application I use VS 2015 when I start application the IDE is hang and not response until I reset OS , after I try to many time the fallowing exception show :

ScriptedSandbox64.exe - fail fast exception 
 a fail fast exception occurred. Exception handlers will not invoked and the process will be terminated immediately .

but when I open another project its work , any idea about this exception and why how to fix it.